# How to wait for multiple callbacks in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to wait for multiple callbacks but I can't figure out a way to do it nicely.

My code is:

```
module.exports.getFilledOnlineFormsOfArray = (formIDs, callback) => {
let forms = [];
for (let i = 0; i < formIDs.length; i++) {
    this.getFilledOnlineFormByID(formIDs[i], (err, filledForm) => {
        if (err) callback(err);
        else forms.push(filledForm);
    });
}
callback(null, forms);
};
```

How do i call `callback(null, forms)` only after every callback of `getFilledOnlineFormByID` (IE `(err, filledForm)`) is resolved?

I came up with a solution of writing:

```
module.exports.getFilledOnlineFormsOfArray = (formIDs, callback) => {
    let forms = [];
    let count = formIDs.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < formIDs.length; i++) {
        this.getFilledOnlineFormByID(formIDs[i], (err, filledForm) => {
            if (err) callback(err);
            else forms.push(filledForm);
            count--;
            if (count === 0)
                callback(null, forms);
        });
    }
};
```

But it feels bad to code it this way. I'm sure there is more elegant solution to this problem.
I looked for answers in the internet but all I found was how to convert it to async functions, and I can't do it in my project right now.

**EDIT :**
I tried to use `Promise.all` like this:

```
module.exports.getFilledOnlineFormsOfArray = (formIDs, callback) => {
    let forms = [];
    let async = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < formIDs.length; i++) {
        async.push(this.getFilledOnlineFormByID(formIDs[i], (err, filledForm) => {
        if (err) callback(err);
        else forms.push(filledForm);
       }));
    }
    Promise.all(async).then(callback(null, forms));
};
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not use `Promises` and leverage `Promise.all`?

Comment: @mwilson I tried that as well, I will add my try to the question

Comment: The MDN doc on [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is helpful. I also learned how to avoid this with the help of [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Comment: You should not use "async" word as a name of the variable. It is the functional word in JS.

Comment: @WiktorMaciej I changed the name of my variable. Still not working. Am I using `Promise.all()` correctly?

Comment: @WiktorMaciej `async` is a valid identifier. It's a keyword but it's not a reserved keyword because the ECMAScript specification wanted JavaScript to remain backwards compatible on the web. But I agree it should be discouraged as an identifier even if it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all these operation to run in parallel, you can promisify your asynchronous operation and then use `Promise.all()` to track when they are all done:

```
const util = require('util');

module.exports.getFilledOnlineFormsOfArray = (formIDs, callback) => {
    // make a promisified version of the method
    if (!this.getFilledOnlineFormByIDPromise) {
        this.getFilledOnlineFormByIDPromise = util.promisify(this.getFilledOnlineFormByID);
    }

    // use Promise.all() to track when all the promises have completed
    Promise.all(formIDs.map(id => {
        return this.getFilledOnlineFormByIDPromise(id);
    })).then(results => {
        callback(null, results);
    }).catch(err => {
        callback(err);
    });    
};
```

Personally, I'd change the interface of `getFilledOnlineFormsOfArray()` to just return a promise and stop using callbacks at all for managing asynchronous operations.  You could also fix the implementation of `this.getFilledOnlineFormByID()` at the source rather than promisifying it here too.  But, I've offered something that will work with the code you've shown.

Note: When using promises, it is best to promisify your lower level operations and then implement all your control flow and error handling using promises.  It's also generally a lot easier (since promises are particularly good at propagating errors for you whereas callbacks are not).  Mixing callbacks and promises at the higher levels of your code can get messy real fast.

Comment: My function is part of a complex project. It's too late for me now to not use callbacks and use promises instead. Isn't there a nice way of doing it with callbacks?

Comment: @OmriAttiya - No, your hack with a counter is what is required with plain callbacks.  That's what `Promise.all()` does internally.  Managing multiple asynchronous operations with callbacks is just a pain.  That's why promises were invented.  They are the better way to code with async operations.  When you start using `async/await` things are even better.  Start learning and coding with promises.  There is no reason to put it off even if you gradually transform.

Answer (score -1):

We can use **async.parallel** to run multi tasklist.

```
const async = require('async');

 module.exports.getFilledOnlineFormsOfArray = (formIDs, callback) => {
  let taskList = [];
  let forms = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < formIDs.length; i++) {
    taskList.push(function(cb){
      this.getFilledOnlineFormByID(formIDs[i], (err, filledForm) => {
          forms.push(filledForm);
          cb(err, filledForm)
       });
    });
  }
  async.parallel(taskList, function (errs, results) {
    if (errs) {
        console.log(errs);
    }
    console.log('Task list done.', results);
  })
};
```